# Get data in SvelteKit after initial load

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

When loading a Sveltekit application, a consecutive number is retrieved from a database. This is done with the function load(), which is formulated in the file +page.server.js and which in turn calls the actual query function, which is located under lib/server/db. During user input, I need the next number from the database. Even after a lot of research, I don't understand how I can use the function again without writing everything a second time. There must be a way to use the existing function again. But how does that work?

Comment: Is this you are looking for: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#rerunning-load-functions-manual-invalidation

Comment: Thank you, that works, I overlooked that.